# Arrows of arbitrary length

Tags: math-mode, pdftex, scaling

Sometimes I need to type an arrow between nouns in my text, e.g.:

```
Foo $\rightarrow$ Bar $\rightarrow$ Baz
```

Is there any way to adjust the length of the arrow? I have tried with `\scalebox` but it also shrinks it vertically, while all I want is to control its length.

Comment: You could use `\xrightarrow{\hspace{2cm}}` (requires `amsmath`) which gives an arrow a bit longer than 2cm. Do you know about `\longrightarrow`?

Comment: Thanks @egreg That's good to know! I actually want it shorter than `\rightarrow` I will try the solution with `\xrightarrow`

Comment: No, shorter arrows are not available (if you don't find a font that has shorter arrows or make them with TikZ)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}

Foo vv \parbox{.5cm}{\rightarrowfill} Bar $\rightarrow$ Baz

\end{document}
```

For lengths shorter than the default `\rightarrow`, you can go to TikZ:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

\newcommand{\Arrow}[1]{%
\parbox{#1}{\tikz{\draw[->](0,0)--(#1,0);}}
}

Foo \Arrow{.1cm}Bar $\rightarrow$ Baz

\end{document}
```

[image]

Too many other arrow tips available to use with TikZ are possible, but, after all I suspect these tiny arrows will be readable.

Comment: Thanks @AboAmmar. I just tried this with a very short arrow (0.1cm), but I still get the same length as the default `$\rightarrow$`. Hmm.

Comment: @AmelioVazquez-Reina -- as egreg commented on your question, there are no shorter horizontal arrows in the computer modern fonts.  there *are* shorter vertical arrows that could possibly be rotated 90 degrees, but that's a nuisance.  however, there are matching arrowheads in the `lasy` font that might be made use of.

Comment: Why `\parbox`? I'd use `\makebox`, instead, with a proper setting for the baseline.

Comment: @egreg That's exactly why I avoid `makebox`; height adjustment. I used `\raisebox{.5\ht\strutbox}` but it's higher than it should be. How much should I raise this?

Comment: `\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\Arrow}[1]{%
  \check@mathfonts
  \raisebox{\fontdimen22\textfont2}{\tikz{\draw[->](0,0)--(#1,0);}}%
} \makeatother` (You should be able to guess the line breaks.)

Comment: What egreg says, plus `\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}` would be certainly good.

Answer (score 2):

Implementing the suggestion by Barbara Beeton of using the arrow head in the `lasy` fonts, which is however smaller than the standard arrow head of `\rightarrow`. It shouldn't be a problem if you always use `\Arrow`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pict2e,picture}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\Arrow}[1][]{%
  \check@mathfonts
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \settowidth{\dimen@}{$\m@th\rightarrow$}%
  \else
    \setlength{\dimen@}{#1}%
  \fi
  \sbox\z@{\usefont{U}{lasy}{m}{n}\symbol{41}}%
  \begin{picture}(\dimen@,\ht\z@)
  \roundcap
  \put(\dimexpr\dimen@-.7\wd\z@,0){\usebox\z@}
  \put(0,\fontdimen22\textfont2){\line(1,0){\dimen@}}
  \end{picture}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

Foo \Arrow[.1cm] Bar $\rightarrow$ Baz

\Arrow\Arrow[1cm]\Arrow[.5cm]

$\rightarrow$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a light weight approach, using no packages, and not even picture environment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\myarrow}[1][1cm]{\mathrel{%
   \hbox{\rule[\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2-.2pt\relax]{#1}{.4pt}}%
   \mkern-4mu\hbox{\usefont{U}{lasy}{m}{n}\symbol{41}}}}

\makeatletter

\setbox0\hbox{$\xdef\scriptratio{\strip@pt\dimexpr
    \numexpr(\sf@size*65536)/\f@size sp}$}

\newcommand{\myscriptarrow}[1][1cm]{{%
    \hbox{\rule[\scriptratio\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2-.2pt\relax]
               {\scriptratio\dimexpr#1\relax}{\scriptratio\dimexpr.4pt\relax}}%
   \mkern-4mu\hbox{\let\f@size\sf@size\usefont{U}{lasy}{m}{n}\symbol{41}}}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[x-a\myarrow b_{c\myscriptarrow d-e}-f\]
\[x-a\myarrow[.5cm] b_{c\myscriptarrow[.5cm] d-e}-f\]
\[x-a\myarrow[1mm] b_{c\myscriptarrow[1mm] d-e}-f\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

As in other answers it implements @BarbaraBeeton's suggestion of using the arrow head in the `lasy` fonts. The length parameter or `\myscriptarrow` is automatically scaled, so it should be same as for `\myarrow`.

---

Equivalent result is obtained via shorter code which  employs `\vcenter`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\myarrow}[1][1cm]{\mathrel{%
   \vcenter{\hbox{\rule[-.2pt]{#1}{.4pt}}}%
   \mkern-4mu\hbox{\usefont{U}{lasy}{m}{n}\symbol{41}}}}

\makeatletter

\setbox0\hbox{$\xdef\scriptratio{\strip@pt\dimexpr
    \numexpr(\sf@size*65536)/\f@size sp}$}

\newcommand{\myscriptarrow}[1][1cm]{{%
    \vcenter{\hbox{\rule[\scriptratio\dimexpr-.2pt\relax]
               {\scriptratio\dimexpr#1\relax}{\scriptratio\dimexpr.4pt\relax}}}%
   \mkern-4mu\hbox{\let\f@size\sf@size\usefont{U}{lasy}{m}{n}\symbol{41}}}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[x-a\myarrow b_{c\myscriptarrow d-e}-f\]
\[x-a\myarrow[.5cm] b_{c\myscriptarrow[.5cm] d-e}-f\]
\[x-a\myarrow[1mm] b_{c\myscriptarrow[1mm] d-e}-f\]
\end{document}
```

The `\myscriptarrow` could use `\mathrel`. The sole effect (in script style for which it is destined) would be to suppress the small space separating from alarge symbol (`\sum`, `\prod`, ...) either immediately preceding or following.

The code for  `\myscriptarrow` can be simplified if one removes the two `\scriptratio` which scale the rule thickness and vertical shift for centering (the one scaling the width must stay).

---

A better choice perhaps for the thickness is to use `\fontdimen8` of the extension font.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\myarrow}[1][1cm]{\mathrel{%
   \vcenter{\hbox{\rule[-.5\fontdimen8\textfont3]{#1}{\fontdimen8\textfont3}}}%
   \mkern-4mu\hbox{\usefont{U}{lasy}{m}{n}\symbol{41}}}}

\makeatletter

\setbox0\hbox{$\xdef\scriptratio{\strip@pt\dimexpr
    \numexpr(\sf@size*65536)/\f@size sp}$}

\newcommand{\myscriptarrow}[1][1cm]{{%
    \vcenter{\hbox{\rule[-.5\fontdimen8\scriptfont3]
               {\scriptratio\dimexpr#1\relax}{\fontdimen8\scriptfont3}}}%
   \mkern-4mu\hbox{\let\f@size\sf@size\usefont{U}{lasy}{m}{n}\symbol{41}}}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[x-a\myarrow b_{c\myscriptarrow d-e}-f\]
\[x-a\myarrow[.5cm] b_{c\myscriptarrow[.5cm] d-e}-f\]
\[x-a\myarrow[1mm] b_{c\myscriptarrow[1mm] d-e}-f\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: 1) I am not sure I should actually use the `[-.5\fontdimen8\textfont3]` for the rule positioning. 2) in last version, the `\scriptratio` serves only for scaling width. It could be dropped then optional parameter gives exact width of script arrow.