# Very short arrow symbol

Tags: arrows, scale

Is there a way to make very short arrows?

I have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}

\begin{document}
$x_{i\shortrightarrow j}$
\end{document}
```

[image: arrow]

I want:

[image: arrow short]

Thank's for all ideas and suggestions!

Comment: Maybe help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/112759/31034

Comment: See this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/270009/101651

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a more light-weight approach. Two macros are defined, one for normal style, the other one for script style. In the latter case the `\mathrel` is dropped as it would have no effect. In the former case the `\mathrel` causes the thing to look a bit smallish compared to surrounding whitespace.

For the script thing, the optional parameter is the desired length *before* the ratio to normal size is taken into account, i.e. it should be normally the same as the one used for the normal size thing.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\veryshortarrow}[1][3pt]{\mathrel{%
   \hbox{\rule[\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2-.2pt\relax]{#1}{.4pt}}%
   \mkern-4mu\hbox{\usefont{U}{lasy}{m}{n}\symbol{41}}}}

\makeatletter

\setbox0\hbox{$\xdef\scriptratio{\strip@pt\dimexpr
    \numexpr(\sf@size*65536)/\f@size sp}$}

\newcommand{\scriptveryshortarrow}[1][3pt]{{%
    \hbox{\rule[\scriptratio\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2-.2pt\relax]
               {\scriptratio\dimexpr#1\relax}{\scriptratio\dimexpr.4pt\relax}}%
   \mkern-4mu\hbox{\let\f@size\sf@size\usefont{U}{lasy}{m}{n}\symbol{41}}}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[x-a\veryshortarrow b_{c\scriptveryshortarrow d-e}-f\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

The `\mkern-4mu` was obtained by trial and error.

Equivalent result is obtained via this little bit shorter code which  employs `\vcenter`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\veryshortarrow}[1][3pt]{\mathrel{%
   \vcenter{\hbox{\rule[-.2pt]{#1}{.4pt}}}%
   \mkern-4mu\hbox{\usefont{U}{lasy}{m}{n}\symbol{41}}}}

\makeatletter

\setbox0\hbox{$\xdef\scriptratio{\strip@pt\dimexpr
    \numexpr(\sf@size*65536)/\f@size sp}$}

\newcommand{\scriptveryshortarrow}[1][3pt]{{%
    \vcenter{\hbox{\rule[\scriptratio\dimexpr-.2pt\relax]
               {\scriptratio\dimexpr#1\relax}{\scriptratio\dimexpr.4pt\relax}}}%
   \mkern-4mu\hbox{\let\f@size\sf@size\usefont{U}{lasy}{m}{n}\symbol{41}}}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[x-a\veryshortarrow b_{c\scriptveryshortarrow d-e}-f\]
\end{document}
```

The `\scriptveryshortarrow` could use `\mathrel`. The sole effect (in script style for which it is destined) would be to suppress the small space separating from alarge symbol (`\sum`, `\prod`, ...) either immediately preceding or following.

The code for  `\scriptveryshortarrow` can be simplified if one removes the two `\scriptratio` which scale the rule thickness and vertical shift for centering (the one scaling the width must stay).

---

A perhaps better choice for the thickness of the rule (rather than `.4pt` as above) is to use `\fontdimen8` of the extension font.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\veryshortarrow}[1][3pt]{\mathrel{%
   \vcenter{\hbox{\rule[-.5\fontdimen8\textfont3]{#1}{\fontdimen8\textfont3}}}%
   \mkern-4mu\hbox{\usefont{U}{lasy}{m}{n}\symbol{41}}}}

\makeatletter

\setbox0\hbox{$\xdef\scriptratio{\strip@pt\dimexpr
    \numexpr(\sf@size*65536)/\f@size sp}$}

\newcommand{\scriptveryshortarrow}[1][3pt]{\mathrel{%
    \vcenter{\hbox{\rule[-.5\fontdimen8\scriptfont3]
               {\scriptratio\dimexpr#1\relax}{\fontdimen8\scriptfont3}}}%
   \mkern-4mu\hbox{\let\f@size\sf@size\usefont{U}{lasy}{m}{n}\symbol{41}}}}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[x-a\veryshortarrow b_{c\scriptveryshortarrow\frac xy}-f\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\mathrel` doesn't add spaces in subscripts.

Comment: @egreg isn't it exactly what I say ?

Comment: What I say is that you *don't* need to drop `\mathrel`.

Comment: why would I _not_ drop it if it serves nothing?

Comment: @egreg it does serve indeed to something if followed by a `\mathop` class object. A `\mathrel` followed by `\mathop` in scriptstyle will induce no spacing, but a `\mathord` followed by `\mathop` will. Omitting the `\mathrel` in the definition means it acts as `\mathord` in scriptstyle, hence some spacing. `x_{a\myscriptarrow\sum b}`. Both with `\sum` and `\prod`, I find the no spacing version a bit better. So perhaps indeed I should have left the `\mathrel`.

Answer (score 7):

If you like the arrow in `stmaryrd`, you can clip it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage{trimclip}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\shortto}{%
  \mathrel{\mathpalette\short@to\relax}%
}

\newcommand{\short@to}[2]{%
  \mkern2mu
  \clipbox{{.5\width} 0 0 0}{$\m@th#1\vphantom{+}{\shortrightarrow}$}%
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$a\shortto b_{c\shortto d}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: My only thought is that the short arrow needs shorter sidebearings...looks way to spaced out in `\textstyle`.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes That's something left to the OP's preference; but I believe the main usage is in subscripts anyway.

Answer (score 1):

CarLaTeX' link provided the answer! Thanks a lot! 
I've modified the solution a bit, see the result below.

(Sorry to everybody who feels hurt by the crude way I've adapted spacing and scaling).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pict2e,picture,graphicx}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\Arrow}[1][]{%
\check@mathfonts
\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
\settowidth{\dimen@}{$\m@th\rightarrow$}%
\else
\setlength{\dimen@}{#1}%
\fi
\sbox\z@{\usefont{U}{lasy}{m}{n}\symbol{41}}%
\begin{picture}(\dimen@,\ht\z@)
\roundcap
\put(\dimexpr\dimen@-.7\wd\z@,0){\usebox\z@}
\put(0,\fontdimen22\textfont2){\line(1,0){\dimen@}}
\end{picture}%
}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\veryshortrightarrow}{\hspace{.2mm}\scalebox{.8}{\Arrow[.1cm]}\hspace{.2mm}}

\begin{document}
    $x_{i\veryshortrightarrow j}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 but this will be same size whether subscript or not

Comment: @jfbu Yes, can confirm that. It is no problem in my case. Certainly, it is not an elegant solution.