# Align & match length of \rightarrow and \xrightarrow

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, amsmath, lengths

In the following example, I want to make `\rightarrow` be the same length as the `\xrightarrow`, while aligning the two.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
A &\xrightarrow{\mathrm{closed\, loop}} B \\
C &\rightarrow D
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

I have found that I can [change the length of `\rightarrow`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269935/arrows-of-arbitrary-length), using `calc`'s `\widthof` to get the length right:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
A &\xrightarrow{\mathrm{closed\, loop}} B \\
C &\parbox{\widthof{$\xrightarrow{\mathrm{closed\, loop}}$}}{\rightarrowfill} D
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

But I then lose the alignment of the two arrows (and I am not happy about using `$...$` while already in an `equation`. Is there a way to align these two arrows? Is there a better way to get two arrows of the same length?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need a `\hphantom`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
A &\xrightarrow{\mathrm{closed\, loop}} B \\
C &\xrightarrow{\hphantom{\mathrm{closed\, loop}}} D
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted! I couldn't figure out how to have `\xrightarrow` _not_ print out the text for the second line, which is why I started messing with `\rightarrow`. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This answer is actually the same with @Schrödinger's. I add two commands to make it conveniant to use.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\firstarrow}[2][default]{
  \expandafter\gdef\csname arrow@content@#1\endcsname{#2}
  \xrightarrow{\@nameuse{arrow@content@#1}}
}
\newcommand{\alignarrow}[1][default]{\xrightarrow{\hphantom{\@nameuse{arrow@content@#1}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
  A &\firstarrow{\mathrm{closed\, loop}} B \\
  A &\alignarrow B\\
  C &\firstarrow[test]{a_c} D\\
  A &\alignarrow B\\
  C &\alignarrow[test] D\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]