circ with tiny arrow inside, or more generally: how to center and overlay math symbols
In the below code, I try to make a new symbol \cilr which is the normal \circ symbol, but a small rightarrow overlayed/centered within it. The horizontal centering I think is probably a lost cause and must be done by hand (especially if I want to use \mathchoice to make this symbol work even in subscripts/subsubscripts), but the vertical centering I imagine should have some command that does it automatically.
\documentclass{article}   
\usepackage{scalerel}

% 10/27/24 https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394985/very-short-arrow-symbol
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269935/arrows-of-arbitrary-length/270009#270009

\newcommand{\myarrow}[1][1cm]{\mathrel{%
   \hbox{\rule[\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2-.2pt\relax]{#1}{.4pt}}%
   \mkern-4mu\hbox{\usefont{U}{lasy}{m}{n}\symbol{41}}}}

\makeatletter

\setbox0\hbox{$\xdef\scriptratio{\strip@pt\dimexpr
    \numexpr(\sf@size*65536)/\f@size sp}$}

\newcommand{\myscriptarrow}[1][1cm]{{%
    \hbox{\rule[\scriptratio\dimexpr\fontdimen22\textfont2-.2pt\relax]
               {\scriptratio\dimexpr#1\relax}{\scriptratio\dimexpr.4pt\relax}}%
   \mkern-4mu\hbox{\let\f@size\sf@size\usefont{U}{lasy}{m}{n}\symbol{41}}}}

\makeatother

\newcommand{\tinyrightVCENTER}{\mathinner{\vcenter{\hbox{{\scaleobj{0.5}{\myarrow[0.12cm]}}}}}}

\newcommand{\tinyright}{\raisebox{0.39\totalheight}{\scaleobj{0.5}{\myarrow[0.12cm]}}}

\newcommand{\cilr}{\mathrel{\circ \hspace{-3.8pt} \tinyrightVCENTER}}



\begin{document}
$\circ, \tinyright,$ 
$\tinyrightVCENTER,$
$\cilr, X_{f\cilr g}, X_{f \circ g}$ 
\end{document}


Does anyone have a nice/elegant way of constructing this symbol? And more generally, what is the method to center new symbols on the math axis (like the scaleobj \tinyarrow above) (this question was raised already in this comment under a similar question), and overlay many symbols on top of each other?
EDIT: below is something I wrote based off of \subseteq + \circ as a single symbol ("open subset")
\newcommand{\tinyright}{\mathchoice
 {\scaleobj{0.5}{\myarrow[0.12cm]}}
 {\scaleobj{0.5}{\myarrow[0.12cm]}}
 {\scaleobj{0.5}{\myscriptarrow[0.11cm]}}
 {\scaleobj{0.5}{\myscriptarrow[0.1cm]}}
 }
%\newcommand{\cilr}{\mathrel{\circ \hspace{-3.8pt} \tinyrightVCENTER}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\cilr{\mathrel{\opncls@{\tinyright}}}
\newcommand{\opncls@}[1]{%
  \vphantom{\circ}% to fix the bounding box
  \mathpalette\opncls@@{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\opncls@@}[2]{%
  \ooalign{$\m@th#1\circ$\cr
  \hidewidth\opncls@fix{#1}\hbox{$\m@th#1#2\mkern2.3mu$}\cr}}

\newcommand\opncls@fix[1]{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle
    \raise.28ex
  \else
    \ifx#1\textstyle
      \raise.28ex
    \else
      \ifx#1\scriptstyle
        \raise.20ex
      \else
        \raise.10ex
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
}


The result is significantly better, but (1) I still think there must be someway to automatically vertically align, instead of calibrating it by hand as in \opncls@fix, and (2) still there is some horizontal adjustments I'd like to make but can't figure out how to do in this framework (e.g. display/textstyle the arrow is a bit too left, and the scriptstyle the arrow is a bit too right)

You asked, "what is the method to center symbols on the math axis"? If the symbol of interest is generated (In math mode) by a macro called \xyz, then $\vcenter\hbox{$\xyz$}$ will place the symbol on the math axis, vertically centered. (Hence the name "vcenter", I suppose.)

@Mico I tried that with my \tinyarrow, but it is not vertically centered with \circ. I assume \circ is centered correctly on the math axis, so something must be wrong with the way I designed \tinyarrow

No, $\circ$ is not centered on the math axis by default. To verify this for yourself, just generate $\circ \vcenter{\hbox{$\circ$}}$. The resulting symbols are not at the same height.

@Mico ah, my mistake. then my question becomes: can I figure out the vertical alignment of \circ, and then have that piped in to set the vertical alignment of \tinyarrow?

The code in @egreg's answer provides informaton about the required height adjustments.

Something like this?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\cilr}{\mathbin{\mathpalette\ci@\rightarrow}}
\newcommand{\cirl}{\mathbin{\mathpalette\ci@\leftarrow}}
\newcommand{\ci@}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\circ$}%
  \vphantom{\copy\z@}%
  \ooalign{\copy\z@\cr\hidewidth\ci@raise{#1}{#2}\hidewidth\cr}%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\ci@raise}[2]{%
  \raisebox{0.35\ht\z@}{\resizebox{0.8\wd\z@}{!}{$\m@th#1\boldsymbol{#2}$}}%
}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}

$A \cilr B \cirl C$

$\scriptstyle A \cilr B \cirl C$

\end{document}


For different math fonts you may need to modify the parameters. For instance, with NewTX a decent result is obtained with
\newcommand{\ci@raise}[2]{%
  \raisebox{0.35\ht\z@}{\resizebox{0.7\wd\z@}{!}{$\m@th#1\boldsymbol{#2}$}}%
}


If you want shorter arrows, you can scale them down further and raise a bit more.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\cilr}{\mathbin{\mathpalette\ci@\rightarrow}}
\newcommand{\cirl}{\mathbin{\mathpalette\ci@\leftarrow}}
\newcommand{\ci@}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\circ$}%
  \vphantom{\copy\z@}%
  \ooalign{\copy\z@\cr\hidewidth\ci@raise{#1}{#2}\hidewidth\cr}%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\ci@raise}[2]{%
  \raisebox{0.4\ht\z@}{\resizebox{0.6\wd\z@}{!}{$\m@th#1\boldsymbol{#2}$}}%
}
\makeatletter

\begin{document}

$A \cilr B \cirl C$

$\scriptstyle A \cilr B \cirl C$

\end{document}



if I want to use \tinyrightarrow or \tinyleftarrow by doing \scaleobj (because I find \rightarrow or \leftarrow to be too long when inside the \circ), then I think they still wouldn't be vertically aligned, right?

@D.R See edit to the answer.
